# How to check accuracy of Ellipsoid Fitting?

Tags: image-processing, github, 3d, pattern-matching

I calibrated magnetometer HMC5883L for my IMU using Ellipsoid Fitting as done in this tip: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/design_tip/group0/a2/98/f5/d4/9c/48/4a/d1/DM00286302/files/DM00286302.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00286302.pdf . 
I get the offsets and the inverse transformation matrix to correct the hard iron and soft iron errors respectively. How can I check for the accuracy of the obtained offsets and transformation matrix? I tried searching for the same and found out two ways. There is the MotionCal GUI by Adafruit and the other one is a python program called PIEFACE. However, both of them use minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid fitting, which is an altogether different method from the one that I am using. Hence comparing my method with either of the two wouldn't be the correct way. Is there a way I can find out the correctness of my results?